# Confusion on assembly output of virtual table in Visual C++ 2015

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, vtable

I'm confused by the assembly output of Visual C++ 2015 (x86).

I want to know the virtual table layout in VC, so I write the following simple class with a virtual function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Foo
{
    virtual int GetValue()
    {
        uintptr_t vtbl = *(uintptr_t *)this;
        uintptr_t slot0 = ((uintptr_t *)vtbl)[0];
        uintptr_t slot1 = ((uintptr_t *)vtbl)[1];

        printf("vtbl = 0x%08X\n", vtbl);
        printf("  [0] = 0x%08X\n", slot0);
        printf("  [1] = 0x%08X\n", slot1);

        return 0xA11BABA;
    }
};

extern "C" void Check();

int main()
{
    Foo *pFoo = new Foo;
    int x = pFoo->GetValue();
    printf("x = 0x%08X\n", x);
    printf("\n");
    Check();
}
```

And to check the layout, I implement an assembly function (the magic name comes from the assembly output `vtab.asm` of `vtab.cpp`, and is the mangled version of `Foo::GetValue`).

```
.model flat

extern _printf : proc
extern ?GetValue@Foo@@UAEHXZ : proc

.const
FUNC_ADDR db "Address of Foo::GetValue = 0x%08X", 10, 0

.code
_Check proc
    push ebp
    mov esp, ebp

    push offset ?GetValue@Foo@@UAEHXZ
    push offset FUNC_ADDR
    call _printf
    add esp, 8

    pop ebp
    ret
_Check endp
end
```

Then, I compile and run.

```
ml /c check.asm
cl /Fa vtab.cpp check.obj
vtab
```

And get the following output on my computer.

```
vtbl = 0x00FF2174
  [0] = 0x00FE1300
  [1] = 0x6C627476
x = 0x0A11BABA

Address of Foo::GetValue = 0x00FE1300
```

It clearly shows the virtual function `GetValue` is at offset 0 of the virtual table. But the assembly output of `vtab.cpp` seems to imply `GetValue` is at offset 4 (see the following comments start with three semicolons).

```
;   COMDAT ??_7Foo@@6B@
CONST   SEGMENT
??_7Foo@@6B@ DD FLAT:??_R4Foo@@6B@          ; Foo::`vftable'
    DD  FLAT:?GetValue@Foo@@UAEHXZ         ;;; GetValue at offset 4
CONST   ENDS

; Function compile flags: /Odtp
;   COMDAT ??0Foo@@QAE@XZ
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_this$ = -4                     ; size = 4
??0Foo@@QAE@XZ PROC                 ; Foo::Foo, COMDAT
; _this$ = ecx
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push    ecx
    mov DWORD PTR _this$[ebp], ecx
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _this$[ebp]
    mov DWORD PTR [eax], OFFSET ??_7Foo@@6B@    ;;; Init ptr to virtual table
    mov eax, DWORD PTR _this$[ebp]
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 0
??0Foo@@QAE@XZ ENDP                 ; Foo::Foo
```

Thanks for your answering!

**Update**

@Hans Passant This seems to be a bug. I `ml /c` the assembly output `vtab.asm` (with a few symbols deletion) and link it with `check.obj` to get an exe `vtab2.exe`. But `vtab2.exe` won't run correctly. Then I modify the following code

```
;   COMDAT ??_7Foo@@6B@
CONST   SEGMENT
??_7Foo@@6B@ DD FLAT:??_R4Foo@@6B@          ; Foo::`vftable'
    DD  FLAT:?GetValue@Foo@@UAEHXZ
CONST   ENDS
```

to

```
;   COMDAT ??_7Foo@@6B@
CONST   SEGMENT
__NOT_USED_ DD  FLAT:??_R4Foo@@6B@          ; Foo::`vftable'
??_7Foo@@6B@    DD  FLAT:?GetValue@Foo@@UAEHXZ
CONST   ENDS
```

and `ml` and `link` again to get `vtab3.exe`. Now `vtab3.exe` runs correctly and produces an output similar to `vtab.exe`.

Comment: No, the v-table has only one entry.  Just Foo::GetValue().  The entry for ??_R4Foo@@6B@ does not belong to the v-table, it is the RTTI object locator.  Compile with /GR- to make it more obvious.  And /d1reportAllClassLayout to get the compiler to give you more info about layout.

Comment: I understand only Foo::GetValue() is in the v-table. My confusion is why `mov DWORD PTR [eax], OFFSET ??_7Foo@@6B@` is not `mov DWORD PTR [eax], OFFSET ??_7Foo@@6B@ + 4`. Anyway, the RTTI object begins at label `??_7Foo@@6B@`, followed by Foo::GetValue().

Comment: What's the assembly code for `GetValue`?

Comment: Maybe it helps if you consider the RTTI object locator to be part of the v-table as well.  It makes dynamic_cast<> work and that requires working off the object pointer.  Keep in mind that the code in the constructor is necessary to implement the C++ language spec requirement that virtual functions are not virtual until the object is constructed.

Comment: @Jester The full output is long and I stripped code for `GetValue` and others. `GetValue` is not special, just a normal function. @Hans Passant  Whether RTTI object locator belongs to the v-table is not relevant. What is important is code of `Foo::Foo` says `GetValue()` is at offset 4, but the output of `vtab.exe` says `GetValue()` is at offset 0.

Comment: I was interested in how `GetValue` fetches the `this` and the `slot[x]` but okay :P

Comment: @Jester I see... `this` pointer is passed by register `ecx`. The action to fetch `slot[x]` takes place in `main` the call site, not in body of the callee `GetValue`. Here is the sequence in `main`: (1) `mov ecx, DWORD PTR _pFoo$[ebp]`;  load the object pointer into register `ecx`; (2) `mov edx, DWORD PTR [ecx]`; load the object virtual table pointer into register `edx`; (3) `mov eax, DWORD PTR [edx]`; load the function pointer into register `eax`; (4) `call eax`; call the function indirectly.

Comment: That only shows how `GetValue` itself is called. I wanted to see how `GetValue` uses `this` to fetch the `slot[0]` in case the compiler adjusts by 4 somewhere so that it hides the RTTI stuff.

Comment: @Jester Here is the workings of GCC. For the definition part, the compiler generates assembly similar to `FooVtbl dd RttiObj; dd Method1; dd Method2`; for the reference part in `Foo::Foo`, the compiler generates `mov eax, this$[ebp]; mov [eax], offsetof FooVtbl + 4`. `+ 4` in `(offsetof FooVtbl) + 4` is the only adjustment, and this is what I think VC assembly output omits (but the machine code is correct). If you are interested, you can run `cl /Fa vtab.cpp` with the C++ code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Microsoft would consider this a bug. Yes, the assembly output should have the vtable symbol on the second element of the vtable so that the RTTI entry appears at offset -4 of the table. However the table should also be in a COMDAT section, but instead there's only a comment in the assembly output (`; COMDAT`) that indicates this. That's because while the PECOFF object file format supports COMDAT sections, the assembler (MASM, invoked as `ml`) doesn't. There's no way for the compiler to generate an assembly file that actually corresponds to the contents of the object file it creates.

Or to put it another way, the assembly output isn't meant to be assembled. It's just meant to be informative. Even with your fix applied the assembly output doesn't generate the same object file the compiler does. If you did this in a more realistic project where `Foo` was used in more than one object file you'd get multiple definition errors when linking. If you want to see the real output of the compiler you need to look at the object file.

For example if you use `dumpbin /all vtab.obj` and go through its output, you'll see something like:

```
SECTION HEADER #C
  .rdata name
...
40301040 flags
         Initialized Data
         COMDAT; sym= "const Foo::`vftable'" (??_7Foo@@6B@)
         4 byte align
         Read Only

RAW DATA #C
  00000000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                          ........

RELOCATIONS #C
                                                Symbol    Symbol
 Offset    Type              Applied To         Index     Name
 --------  ----------------  -----------------  --------  ------
 00000000  DIR32                      00000000        34  ??_R4Foo@@6B@ (const Foo::`RTTI Complete Object Locator')
 00000004  DIR32                      00000000        1F  ?GetValue@Foo@@UAEHXZ (public: virtual int __thiscall Foo::GetValue(void))

...

COFF SYMBOL TABLE
...
026 00000000 SECTC  notype       Static       | .rdata
    Section length    8, #relocs    2, #linenums    0, checksum        0, selection    6 (pick largest)
028 00000004 SECTC  notype       External     | ??_7Foo@@6B@ (const Foo::`vftable')
```

It's not easy to understand, but all the information about the actual layout of the vtable is given.  The symbol for the vtable, `` ??_7Foo@@6B@ (const Foo::`vftable') ``, is at offset `00000004` of `SECTC` or section number 0xC. Section #C is 8 bytes long and has relocations for the RTTI locator and `Foo::GetValue` that are applied at offsets `00000000` and `00000004` of the section. So you can see that in the object file the vtable symbol does in fact point to the entry containing the pointer to the first virtual method.

Open Watcom has a utility that can show you the contents of an object file in a more assembly-like fashion, though notably not in the syntax that MASM uses. Running `wdis t279.obj` shows:

```
                .new_section .rdata, "dr2"
0000    00 00 00 00                                     .long   ??_R4Foo@@6B@
0004                          ??_7Foo@@6B@:
0004    00 00 00 00                                     .long   ?GetValue@Foo@@UAEHXZ
```

Comment: I agree the assembly output is not meant to be reassembled, but I do believe it should be correct to some extent. The output can help programmers understand the inner workings of the compiler. Incorrect assembly only leads to confusion, which is against our purpose. I'm not familiar with object files, but I don't think the section matters. Whatever the section is, relative offsets are the same and the question remains.

Comment: This may be a simple bug. The compiler internal structure is correct, but when output, something is wrong, either the programmer outputs the v-table label at a wrong place (should point to the first virtual function, but point to the RTTI object incorrectly), or the v-table pointer initialization is wrong (should be `mov [ecx], offset VTableLabel + 4`, but output `mov [ecx], offset VTableLabel` instead).

Comment: @HuaidongXiong What you think the purpose is of the assembly output of the compiler doesn't matter. All that matters is what Microsoft thinks the purpose is. You can report this as a bug if you want, but don't hold your breath waiting for them to fix it. There's nothing wrong with the object file (.OBJ) the compiler generates, and this is the output that matters. Except in trivial cases, the contents are of the assembly file are always incorrect and this is by design. Fundamentally the assembly file cannot accurately represent the compiler's intended output.

Comment: Are you kidding? If `mov [ecx], offset VTableLabel + 4` is not trivial, what is? If the incorrect output is by design, the only thing I can say is "MS did this on purpose so that assembly output won't be reassembled easily, but what is the point, :)". A bug is a bug, don't stare at somewhere else and  say something irrelevant (顾左右而言他). BTW, I do report this as a bug, but I won't wait for them to fix it. I use Mac and Linux only when working. I post this thread just because the incorrect output make me confused when I learn assembly and compare the output of VC and GCC.

Comment: @HuaidongXiong Fixing the assembler output so it correctly represents the actual output of the compiler is not trivial. Just fixing that one little bug won't solve the fundamental problem.

Comment: Thanks for your update, it's quite helpful for my assembly learning. So, the compiler builds a correct internal structure in which `??_7Foo@@6B@` points to the first virtual method, but the assembly output seems imply `??_7Foo@@6B@` points to the RTTI locator. Output of Open Watcom utility `wdis` is much better. I still don't understand the meaning of `; COMDAT ??_7Foo@@6B@` and why `VC++` is designed not to give an output similar to`wdis`.